# Using a ActionScript class in a different actionscript file (in a same folder)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a file with name `Enemy.as` and its content is

```
package{
    import flash .display.*;
    public class Enemy extends MovieClip{
        public function Enemy(){
            var randomC_x:Number=Math.random();
            var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            mc.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            mc.graphics.drawCircle(randomC_x,0,3);
            mc.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(mc);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have also a file called main.as and in this main.as I want to create Enemy instances and use them. How could I do that  ?

I mean

```
// my Main.as File
package{
    import flash .display.*;
    public class Main extends MovieClip{
        public function Main(){
           // I need to create an Enemy object here .

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package{
    import flash .display.*;
    public class Main extends MovieClip{

        private var _enemy1:Enemy = new Enemy();

        public function Main(){
          addChild(_enemy1);
          _enemy1.x = ...
          _enemy1.y = ....
         etc etc

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply , I've just a couple hours experience with as3, in c++ I need to use like #include "externalfile.cpp". Doesnt it necessary in actionScript ?

Comment: That's cool. Not if the Classes are in the same folder/package. Good luck :)